# webvirt authentication

Tags: python, kvm, qemu

I am using webvirt in order to play with a web page and have a quick access to my VMs (qemu setup). My problem is that when I try to open a console for any of my guest domains, in the server side I have to provide the credentials in order to open the new window and have access to the domain. 
Is there any way to accomplish without the need of repetitive authentications?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Okay, found it. I had to edit my graphics settings in the domain xml like the following:

```
<graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes' websocket='-1' listen='0.0.0.0' passwd='mypassword'>
  <listen type='address' address='0.0.0.0'/>
</graphics>
```

Setting port to -1 with autoport to yes and websocket to -1 you are letting webvirt dynamically deside the port forwarding for each console request (as far as I can understand).

Thanks anyways :-)